# Socket Creation Error in Linux but not MacOS

Tags: c, sockets, ping

I have the following program where I am attempting to re-create ping. This works great when run in my macOS dev environment, but when running in my prod Linux environment the socket fails to get created. I can't figure out why. In addition, any way to resolve this so it works on Linux would be great.

```
#include <stdio.h> 
#include <stdlib.h> 
#include <unistd.h> 
#include <sys/types.h> 
#include <sys/socket.h> 
#include <netinet/in.h> 
#include <arpa/inet.h> 

/* Calculate ICMP checksum */
uint16_t ip_checksum(void *icmp_header, int size_of_header){
    unsigned short *buffer = icmp_header;
    unsigned int sum = 0;
    uint16_t result;

    for(sum=0;size_of_header > 1; size_of_header -=2){
        sum += *buffer++;
    }

    if(size_of_header == 1){
        sum += *(unsigned char*)buffer;
    }

    sum = (sum >> 16) + (sum & 0xffff);
    result = ~sum;
    return result;
}

int main(int argc, char const *argv[]){
    char ip[20]; /* Define variable to hold user entered IP address*/
    const int icmp_size=8; /* Size of icmp header */

    struct sockaddr_in toSendTo; /* Set sockaddr_in struct */

    /* Create ICMP header */
    struct icmp_header{ 
        unsigned char icmph_type;
        unsigned char icmph_code;
        uint16_t icmph_checksum;
        unsigned short int icmph_ident;
        unsigned short int icmph_seqnum;
    } icmp_header;

    /* Get user to input IP address */
    printf("Please enter an IP address: ");
    fgets(ip, sizeof(ip), stdin);

    /* Loop to send 3 pings requests */
    for(int i = 0; i < 3; i++){
        
        icmp_header.icmph_type = 8; /* Set ICMP type to 8 for sending ICMP request */
        icmp_header.icmph_code = 0; /* Set ICMP code to 0 for sending ICMP request */
        icmp_header.icmph_checksum = 0; /* Initializee checksum to 0 */
        icmp_header.icmph_seqnum = i*20; /* Arbitrary sequence number */
        icmp_header.icmph_ident = i+50; /* Arbitrary id */
        icmp_header.icmph_checksum = ip_checksum(&icmp_header,icmp_size); /* Calculate checksum */

        /* Set transport IP in sockaddr struct  */
        if (inet_addr(ip) == -1){
            printf("Error, invalid IP address\n");
            exit(1);
        }else{
            toSendTo.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr(ip);
        }

        /* Create socket */
        int soc = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_RAW, IPPROTO_ICMP);

        /* Check if creation of socket throws an error */
        if(soc == -1){
            printf("Error creating socket\n");
            exit(1);
        }
        
        /* Send ICMP ping request */
        int send = sendto(soc, &icmp_header, icmp_size, 0, (struct sockaddr *)&toSendTo, sizeof(toSendTo));
        
        /* Check if sending ICMP request throws an error */
        if (send < 0){
            printf("Error sending ping(%d).\n", i+1);
            exit(1);
        }else{
            printf("\nICMP Echo Request(%d) sent to %s", i+1,ip);
        }

        
        unsigned int response_address_size; /* Variable for size of response packet  */
        char response_buffer[50]; /* Buffer for content of response */
        struct sockaddr response_address; /* Struct to hold response address */

        /* Struct to hold ICMP response header information */
        typedef struct icmp_resp{
            unsigned char icmph_type;
            unsigned char icmph_code;
            uint16_t icmph_checksum;
            unsigned short int icmph_ident;
            unsigned short int icmph_seqnum;
        } icmp_r;

  
        /* Receive ICMP response */
        int resp = recvfrom(soc, response_buffer, sizeof(response_buffer), 0, &response_address, &response_address_size);

        /* Check if receiving response throws an error */
        if (resp < 0){
            printf("Error receiving response (%d)\n",i+1);
            exit(1);
        }

        icmp_r* echo_response;

        echo_response = (icmp_r *)&response_buffer[20];

        /* Determine if Destination Unreachable is response */
        if(echo_response->icmph_type == 3 && echo_response->icmph_code == 0){
            printf("Destination Unreachable...\n");
        }else{

            /* Print ICMP response information */
            printf("ICMP Response(%d) : type=%d,code=%d,checksum=%x, ident=%d, seq=%d\n\n", i+1,
                                                                            echo_response->icmph_type,
                                                                            echo_response->icmph_code,
                                                                            ntohs(echo_response->icmph_checksum),
                                                                            echo_response->icmph_ident,
                                                                            echo_response->icmph_seqnum);
        }
        
        /* Close Socket */
        close(soc);

    }
    
}
```

Here is my output when run in Linux:

```
Please enter an IP address: 8.8.8.8
Error creating socket
```

Comment: Call `perror` to get a more precise error string.

Comment: The output of `perror` is `Operation not permitted.`

Comment: when compiling, always enable the warnings. Then fix those warnings.  ( for `gcc`, at a minimum use: `-Wall -Wextra -Wconversion -pedantic -std=gnu11` )  Note: other compilers use different options to produce the same thing.  The OPs posted code results in LOTS of warnings, all of which need to be corrected

Comment: regarding: `*buffer++;`  this has a precedence problem.  Suggest: `(*buffer)++;`

Comment: regarding: `fgets(ip, sizeof(ip), stdin);`  1) there will be a '\n' at the end of the IP value that needs to be removed.  Perhaps via: `ip[ strcspn( ip, "\n" ) ] = '\0';`  Also, strongly suggest validating the value (always validate user input)

Comment: regarding: `int resp = recvfrom(soc, response_buffer, sizeof(response_buffer), 0, &response_address, &response_address_size);`  the function: `recvfrom()` returns a `ssize_t` NOT a `int`

Comment: regarding: `printf("Error receiving response (%d)\n",i+1);`  error messages should be output to `stderr`, NOT `stdout` and when the error indication is from a C library function should also output to `stderr` the text reason the system thinks the error occurred.  The function: `perror()` is made for this purpose.

Comment: if your trying to emulate 'ping' then(perhaps) you could also incorporate the total loop time (usually in milliseconds)  and the number of 'hops'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to set `ping_group_range` with `sysctl` like in the example below for specifying the groups who can create `IPPROTO_ICMP` sockets.

```
sysctl -w net.ipv4.ping_group_range="gid gid"
```

From the [documentation](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/icmp.7.html):

> ping_group_range (two integers; default: see below; since Linux
> 2.6.39)
> Range of the group IDs (minimum and maximum group IDs,
> inclusive) that are allowed to create ICMP Echo sockets.
> The default is "1 0", which means no group is allowed to
> create ICMP Echo sockets.

**Edit**

The socket type has to be `SOCK_DGRAM` instead of `SOCK_RAW` in `int soc = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, IPPROTO_ICMP);` and you also need to define `toSendTo.sin_family = AF_INET;`.

Comment: My linux environment has just the one user, and after running `id -g username` I see the GID is 1000. So running `sysctl -w net.ipv4.ping_group_range=" 1000 1000"` still creates the same error.

Comment: Could you clarify where/how to define `toSendTo.sin_family = AF_INET;` ?

Comment: @sudo-potato The `toSendTo` struct is used by the `sendto` function, so it needs to defined before `sendto` is called. I would add `toSendTo.sin_family = AF_INET;` just before you set the ip address with `toSendTo.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr(ip);`.

Comment: That was great. Thanks!

Comment: @sudo-potato You're welcome! It is not related to the question, but if you want you can also include `netinet/ip_icmp.h`. Then, you can assign `icmp_header.icmph_type = ICMP_ECHO;` instead of `icmp_header.icmph_type = 8;`. It also contains a struct `struct icmphdr`.